# Laravel add new item to foreach loop from outside

Tags: php, laravel, loops, eloquent, helper

I am curious. Is Laravel giving us an easier way to add foreign items to foreach array? For example i have:

```
$video_url = Video::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->url;
$cut_head = str_after($video_url, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
$cut_tail = str_before($cut_head, '&');
```

It works as i think. Cutting head and tail. But in my videos loop. There is no cropped video url link.

```
$videos = Video::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

$videos is using in my view. Inside a foreach loop. How can i entegrate the cropped url_link to the foreach loop.

Thanks an advance.

Comment: Show us your controllers, what are you passing into the view? As it is, $videos has no relation to the first snippet you posted.

Comment: you can do this same process in your foreach also

Comment: you want to add the property url_link in the foreach loop for the videos array?

Comment: @flex_ thats right sir.

Comment: @afsalc yes i can. But there is one problem. str_after and str_before is laravel command. Not php. I need to do this in the controller right? View shouldn't see the str_after command.

Comment: I think the laravel helper function can access from view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created App\Helper\helper.php
added

```
    function videoJpg($video_url){
    $cut_head = str_after($video_url, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
    $cut_tail = str_before($cut_head, '&');
    $video_jpg = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/".$cut_tail."/hqdefault.jpg";

    return $video_jpg;}
```

added

```
"classmap": "database"
"psr-4": {"App\\": "app/" }
"files" : ["app/Helper/helper.php"]
```

to composer.json

After that composer dumpautload

Usage in the blade is: `<img src="{{ VideoJpg($video->url) }}"`

I made my own helper. This is the cleanest solution.